# Django - Many To Many after filtering one end of the relationship, counting backwards always produces the value 1

Tags: django, database, filter, count, many-to-many

I have two models that are in a Many To Many relationship, and I want the following effect to occur:

- Consider models `A` and `B` in a many to many relationship with eachother.
- `A`'s related_name for `B` is `bs` and `B`'s related name for `A` is `as`
- Whenever I create an `A` or `B` it will always be immediately connect to one or more of the other, so initially all instances of `A` and `B` will have at least one related object.
- If I want to delete an `A` (let's call it `a0`) I want it to delete all `B`s that would be left with no related `A`'s after `a0` is deleted, so essentially I want to delete all `B` that have only `a0` in their related_set `as` (the reverse example of this would also be expected).

The way I was trying to implement this is, when I want to delete an `A` such as `a0`, I would say:

```
a0.bs.annotate(Count('bs')).filter(bs__count=1).delete()
```

However this would unconditionally delete ALL related `B` instances in `a0.bs`, and when I went to the shell to test it out, when I would get this result:

```
>>> a0.bs.annotate(Count('bs')).values_list('bs__count',flat=True)
<QuerySet [1, 1, 1, 1]>
>>> B.objects.filter(as=a0).annotate(Count('bs')).values_list('bs__count',flat=True)
<QuerySet [1, 1, 1, 1]>
```

But I would also get this if I did this with the same database instance:

```
>>> B.objects.annotate(Count('bs')).filter(as=a0).values_list('bs__count',flat=True)
<QuerySet [1, 4, 6, 6]>
```

So it is the case that 3 out of the 4 of these `B` instances owuldn't satisfy `count == 1` but they all satisfy if I filter for the specific `B` instances I want to look at before annotating, which seems significantly more efficient than the last command used (the one with the accurate result).

Can anyone give me any insight on this effect?

Comment: this is not a math problem to use A, B, a0 and b0, use proper variable names

Answer (score 0):

Can't you assume that any B record that does not have any related A records to it should be deleted as well? The same is true vice-versa as well.

```
A.objects.filter(pk=1).delete()
B.objects.filter(as=None).delete()
```